# What function to use for performing an AND Operation over bitmaps created in Snowflake DB?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have been playing around with bitmaps using Roaring bitmap library outside Snowflake and have been able to perform simple boolean operations like OR/AND.

I then read that Snowflake support out of box bitmap creation within the database and allows their querying as well.

I was able to construct a table that had numeric ids which I converted to bitmaps and ran aggregate operations like BITMAP_OR_AGG to find out all common ids when I group the data on certain attribute.

For instance, count(ids) where attribute=car_driver_gmc or attribute=car_driver_ford

I am posting sample data/work done over Snowflake databases so far for reference.

Input Sample Data Before converting to bitmaps-

| attribute | incremental_id |
| --- | --- |
| car_driver_gmc | 1 |
| car_driver_ford | 2 |
| car_driver_ford | 3 |
| car_driver_bmw | 4 |
| car_driver_bmw | 5 |
| car_driver_audi | 6 |

Query to convert the input data to bitmap format -

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP.POC.PRECOMPUTE AS SELECT attribute, BITMAP_BUCKET_NUMBER(incremental_id) bucket, BITMAP_CONSTRUCT_AGG(BITMAP_BIT_POSITION(incremental_id)) bmp FROM TEMP.POC.BITMAP_INPUT GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

| attribute | bucket | bmp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| car_driver_gmc | 200 | 001101100101.... |
| car_driver_ford | 200 | 0101010111011.... |
| car_driver_ford | 201 | 0101010111011.... |
| car_driver_bmw | 201 | 0101001111011.... |
| car_driver_bmw | 200 | 0101010111011.... |
| car_driver_audi | 201 | 0101010111011.... |

Query to do a Bitmap Aggregation (OR Operation) -

```
select SUM(cnt) from (select BITMAP_COUNT(BITMAP_OR_AGG(bmp)) as cnt from (select bmp, BUCKET from TEMP.POC.PRECOMPUTE where attribute in ('car_driver_ford','car_driver_bmw','car_driver_audi'))x group by BUCKET)
```

This will return 6

However, I am unable to find a way to actually run a AND query over bitmaps created in these databases. There is no pre-existing function that allows to do a direct AND operation over bitmaps in these databases. I have tried to intersect the attributes, it gives 0 count always.

Any ideas to perform AND operation over bitmaps in Snowflake will help me explore this further.

Comment: You are looking for an aggregation that ANDs the values? Like three rows with the binary values 0111, 0101 and 1100 resulting in 0100?

Comment: Taking Snowflake as the db here, the data in my table has three columns - 
age, bucket, bitmap where age contains numeric values as given in my example. Bucket is how the data in Snowflake is clustered and then bitmap is computed over the unique ids.
I want to find out how many ids are common b/w age=10 and age=20 by querying over the bitmaps
Not necessary looking for an aggregation query, but an operator/query that will allow intersection of bitmaps

Comment: Please update your question with sample data and the result you want to achieve. Also, can you include the SQL you’ve managed to write yourself e.g. how you are converting the numeric values to bitmaps

Comment: Please split this question into 2 questions so it can only have one right answer (one for Snowflake, one for Oracle)

Comment: Updated the question for just snowflake at the moment, thank you.

Comment: I was able to solve my own question. Apparently, there is no implicit operator in Snowflake that allows to the a logical AND Operation/Intersection b/w 2 bitmaps. The only possible way to do OR/AND is to group your data intelligently while creating the bitmaps and then use queries that can mimic an AND operation by leveraging the columns used for Grouping. I'll add the full answer in the question for anybody else wondering how to do it.